# How to extract values that is 15% greater than mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Please refer to the picture for the dataframe[Set of data frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mel44.png)

I got the mean of dividends with:
mean=df["Dividends"].mean()

and got the values that exceeded 15% of mean with:
exc=mean+mean*0.15

The question is how do I display values that exceeded 15% of the mean?
or is there any easier ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df[df['Dividents'] >= (df['Dividents'].mean() * 1.15)]
```

Comment: but when i run the programme, the programme shows me values in interest and other sections too, how do i only get whats in dividends

Comment: df[df['Dividents'] >= (df['Dividents'].mean() * 1.15)].Dividents